# socket_write Php byte[]

Tags: php, sockets

i have a code in c# and here use GetBytes(msg) for SSlStream.write, here send and received data correctly, here all work fine, now i want to make the same event in php, but here i cant see a SslSteam or similar(i think no problem, becouse i working with socket_connection, and i think SSL is only for security), now for compare i stop the code in c# for see what data is sending and try to convert in php, for send here, i can see a data byte{} in c# and with $message=unpack('C*',$message); i can convert the string to byte[], comparing with c# value is the same so, here all is ok, my problem is when i try to write the request, becouse in SslStream.write accpet byte[] but socket_write no accept whe i try send socket_write($socket, '\n', strlen($message)) i have a error : socket_write() expects parameter 2 to be string and obvius is becouse socket_write() only accept string, but so.. as i can send my byte[], becouse the server only accept a byte[] please help me

PD> my problem is how i can send the byte[], i dont know if can send eq socket_write($socket, $message[1], strlen($message)), note please byte is array eq with 70 items, etc

Answer (score 1):

When reading you started with:

```
$message = unpack('C*',$message);
```

So when writing perform the reverse.

---

If you're on PHP 5.6 or higher use:

```
$message = pack('C*', ...$message);
```

Or for earlier versions, which didn't have splat operator:

```
$message = call_user_func_array(
    "pack",
    array_merge(array("C*"), $message)
);
```